More control over Youtube recommendations on religion
I am a religious Jew. I enjoy watching videos by Rabbis on Torah and Judaism.
Youtube now thinks that I like "religion", and sends me any and all religious videos.
I don't want that. Repeatedly flagging these videos as "not interested" is going nowhere. Is there anything I can do?


Clear your search & watch history of those videos.
Don't hit "like" for those videos & Remove them from liked videos.
Watch those videos in incognito mode or while being logged out of your google
account.


+1 for some tips I didn't know, however I am not convinced this will work. If I do it diligently, the moment I click on a new Torah video, my feed will fill with Christian, Muslim, Hindu and Buddhist videos galore. It's not the end of the world, some of those are interesting of course, but I would really like to know how to tune the algorithm a bit more precisely. This is a bit of a hammer, and I am looking for tweezers!
